# What is the difference between transport proteins and effector proteins in gram-negative bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, pathogenesis, host-pathogen-interaction

When considering pathogenic gram-negative bacteria, is there any difference between the function of  transport proteins and effector proteins? Or are they of the same functionality? Any reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Any difference with what? Gram positive, non-pathogenic strains? Please  expand your question to make it more clear.

Comment: This is a pretty clear question. It's asking for the difference between two types of proteins involved in bacterial pathogenesis. They are often not well described in microbiology classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the function of transport proteins and effector proteins?

Yes. In this context, the term "effector proteins" refers to proteins that are inserted into a host cell on infection to modulate host cell processes. Effector proteins are inserted into a host cell using a secretion system. The proteins involved in the secretion system are transport proteins, but the effector proteins themselves have a wide variety of functions. They include enzymes, transcription factors, and protein-protein interaction partners, and they have been shown to regulate many host cellular processes, from metabolism, to vesicular trafficking, cell adhesion, and apoptosis.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21517912).  [This review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22425230) has an interesting perspective, and the Wikipedia page on [Bacterial effector proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacterial_effector_protein) isn't bad either.